# getSupportFragmentManager() - undefined for the type Context

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-context

How do I solve the following problem when instanciationg a Fragment class

```
holder.infoView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
    public void onClick(View v) {
       Fragment infoFragment = new ExampleFragment();
                    infoFragment.show(context.getSupportFragmentManager(), "settings");

     ....
```

the actual class (MySimpleArrayAdapter) which this code is part of - **does not** extend FragmentActivity - **but** takes a *context* (via the constructor) from another class that extends that class.

All the same I cannot use the context such as

```
 infoFragment.show(context.getSupportFragmentManager(), "settings");
```

*I get the error:the method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type Context.*

Is there a simple solution to this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two options:

- First, you can call `getSupportFragmentManager()`in your FragmentActivity, save it as a variable and pass it to your Adapter as a second constructor parameter.
- When you are sure that the Context Object is always derived from the FragmentActivity class, you can cast the Context object to FragmentActivity. Then you can call method, like  `((FragmentActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager()`.

I hope that helped!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this method is only defined for Activity class. Also if you decide to pass Activity instance to your adapter, that's not a very good idea. Consider using interfaces with Observer pattern to communicate between Adapter and Activity.